# View file tree in Sublime when using Cyberduck

Tags: macos, ssh, sublime-text-2, sftp, cyberduck

I use Cyberduck to open remote files and edit them via Sublime on my local machine.

I want to be able to see the file tree of the remote system in the Sublime Text side bar. I've tried a few things but I'm stumped.

Is this possible to achieve using Cyberduck? If not, what is the simplest and fastest (in terms of setup time) way to achieve it?

Comment: Do you have Sublime configured as an external editor in Cyberduck?

Comment: Yes, but it won't let me select "edit in Sublime" on a folder like you can do from osx. Cyberduck only lets me open files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you configure an external editor in Cyberduck (or any FTP/SFTP client), the Cyberduck downloads the edited file to a local temporary folder; runs the editor (Sublime) to open the local file; and re-uploads the edited file back to FTP/SFTP.

So the editor (Sublime) does not even know that the file comes from FTP/SFTP, let alone be able to access the FTP/SFTP site to display the tree.

Though there are FTP/SFTP plugins for Sublime. If you use such plugin, you can work with remote FTP/SFTP files like there are local. You won't need to use Cyberduck.